# How to append a newly created input to newly created li element

Tags: javascript

I want to dynamically add `<li>` elements to a `<ul>` .But every `<li>` element should have a input element inside it. So both of them should be newly created and appended. Can someone tell me how it is done

```js
function add_down() {

  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.type = text;
  element.placeholder = "Enter Name";
  document.getElementById("first").appendChild(node);

  //how to append element to node

}
```

```html
<div style="">
  <div>
    <ul id="start" style="list-style:none">
      <li><input type="text" placeholder="category"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add_down()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your `ID="first"`? I suppose you want to add `li` under `ul`... If that is a case, then  change your last `js` line into `document.getElementById("start").appendChild(node);`

Comment: should try: `element.type = 'text'`, `node.appendChild(element);` `document.getElementById("start").appendChild(node);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append the newly created input to the *li* element first. Then append that *li* to the *ul* element. Also node type *text* should be in the form of string:

Try the following way:

```js
function add_down() {

  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.type = 'text';
  element.placeholder = "Enter Name";
  node.append(element);

  document.getElementById("start").appendChild(node);

}
```

```css
input[type=text]{
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div style="">
  <div>
    <ul id="start" style="list-style:none">
      <li><input type="text" placeholder="category"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add_down()"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same way you are appending the `li` to the `ul`, you can use `appendChild` to put the `input` in the `li`. Also, there are some issues with your code:

- `element.type = text;` should be `element.type = "text";`.
- There's no `ul` with `id="first"`, I suppose you meant to target the `ul` with `id="start"`.

```js
function add_down() {
  var node = document.createElement("li");
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.type = "text";
  element.placeholder = "Enter Name";
  node.appendChild(element); // <-- append element to node
  document.getElementById("start").appendChild(node);
}
```

```html
<div style="">
  <div>
    <ul id="start" style="list-style:none">
      <li><input type="text" placeholder="category"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add_down()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for pointing out my mistake  , I m new to javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_down() {
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.type = "text";
  element.placeholder = "Enter Name";
  node.appendChild(element)
  document.getElementById("start").appendChild(node);             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are only few pointers in your code, your appending the `node` variable to a none existing element with an id `first` then you just only need to append the `element` variable to the `node` variable then append it to main `<ul>`. And also `text` whatsoever is not define.

I hope this helps.

```js
function add_down() {

  var node = document.createElement("li");
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.type = "";                    //text is not define
  element.placeholder = "Enter Name";
  node.appendChild(element);           //Append the it to the node
  document.getElementById("start").appendChild(node);

}
```

```html
<div style="">
  <div>
    <ul id="start" style="list-style:none">
      <li><input type="text" placeholder="category"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add_down()"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Without button

```html
<div style="">
  <div>
    <ul id="start" style="list-style:none">
      <li><input id='input1' type="text" placeholder="category" onchange="add_down()"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("input1").focus()
function add_down() {
  var node = document.createElement("li");
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.setAttribute("onchange", "add_down();");
  element.type = "text";
  element.placeholder = "Enter Name";
  node.appendChild(element); // <-- append element to node
  document.getElementById("start").appendChild(node);
  element.focus();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First your should create your LI element and then create a INPUT element and add the input element to the created LI element and finally append the LI element which is contained the input element to the UL element 
you can use this code

```
    <script>
    function add_down() {
       var node = document.createElement("LI");
       var element = document.createElement("input"); 
       element.setAttribute('type', "text");
       element.setAttribute('placeholder', "Enter Name");
       node.appendChild(element);
       document.getElementById("start").appendChild(node);
    }
    </script>
```